# DlibDotNet exception while running a unit test: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'DlibDotNetNative'

Tags: linux, .net-core, face-recognition, dlib

I'm trying to run a unit test written for a service, that provides face detection functions. But, when it tries to use 
$ Dlib.GetFrontalFaceDetector()
It throws an exception

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'DlibDotNetNative' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libDlibDotNetNative: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

1. I tried to set up a LD_DEBUG variable like this:

set LD_DEBUG=./home/userhome/.nuget/packages/dlibdotnet/19.16.0.20190223/lib/netstandard2.0/

2. I tried to copy a binary file DlibDotNet.dll into a folder with other binaries (<...>/Debug/netcoreapp2.2)

```
public void bool DetectFace()
{
       using (var detector = Dlib.GetFrontalFaceDetector())
       using (var img = Dlib.LoadImage<Byte>(path))
       {
<smth>
       }
<smth>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a decision:

1. ldd ./libDlibDotNetNative.so
2. In output : libopenblas.o.0 - not found
3. sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base
4. Profit!